# How to access artifacts folder after build in TFS online?

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, .net-core

PreInfo: I have .net core web api (vs2015) mixed with just ordinary projects.

I have spent almost 2 days now to get this to work and search and tried everything I can think of, but I just cant for the live of me get the build and release in TFS online to play together.

The build (publish artifact step) says "**Directory 'D:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.**"

but the "run dot net" step says

"Published to D:\a\1\s\Operator\MobileService\root\MobileService\src\AMP.Operator.MobileService\bin\release\net452\win7-x64\publish"

...so **it must be somewhere** the release can pick it up but no matter what I try I can´t get it to be picked up.

Here is my build setup
[image: My build]

dotnet run
[image: dotnet run]

publishing
[image: the publish]

And the realse with $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MobileService-Dev **please note** that I have tried every combo of $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) in the build to publish without luck but I sure this should point to the publishing folder for the build
[image: realse]

I so hope somebody can point me to a solution. I just can´t understand how hard it is to make this work..

Comment: What's the result after trying it with my solution?

Answer (score 24):

Within your build definition, I recommend adding a `Copy Files` step that will copy your the build artifacts from your `msbuild` results to the Build's Artifact Staging Directory before you run the `Publish Artifact` step.

- Source Folder: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`
- Contents: `**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**`
- Target Folder: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`

[image: Copy Files Task]

I am assuming that the `$(BuildConfiguration)` variable is custom to your definition and is probably `Debug` or `Release`. I am not sure what exactly the *Run dotnet* step does, but this build definition I setup published my build artifacts correctly. The Publish Build Artifacts step I'm running has the same steps as yours, except the only control option enabled is `Enabled`.

I am also running on TFS 2015 update 2.

Comment: I think my problem is totally dotnet core related somehow.. your approach did not work I´m sorry. Now I´m looking at his https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/vsts-continuous-deployment

Comment: @Sturla Thanks for the feedback. I also noticed that your working directory for your dotnet tool is a TFS path instead of a _real_ path. I'm not sure if that's intentional or if it might be causing problems. It may be a parameter to use instead of your working directory.

Comment: Shouldn't a build result be placed to artifacts folder 'by definition' without any additional steps copying by hand?

Comment: @SerG If you're talking about the copy to the `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, this is not done automatically. The result of the build (bin and obj folders) remains in the source folder (the `s` folder aka `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`). If your target folder is the ArtifactStagingDirectory (the `a` folder) and you don't preform some kind of copy to it, then no files will be published. Documentation on this variable can be found [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables)

Comment: I've got it already. Looks like the logic changed from 2015 to 2017 TFS or I was just confused.

Answer (score 10):

You can download the files if you just want to take a look at them. Go to the build, click on the Artifacts tab, and then download as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I can't see the image but using Copy task and Publish task separated (Copy&Publish has been deprecated) Artifacts tab is no more shown.
Any workarounds to make it appear?

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify output argument (--output/-o) for dotnet publish command.
Arguments:

```
Publish -c $(BuildConfiguration) -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

BTW: You said “run dot net” step says “Published to D:\a\1\s....”, the files are in D:\a\1\s, no files in D:\a\1\a (one is **s** and another is **a**).

Comment: My build artifact steps says

2018-04-25T19:30:24.0964490Z Upload 'C:\Users\userrr\Downloads\vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.122.1_work\4\s' to file container: '#/917/drop'

where can i find path '#/917/drop' Its not under my agent or TFS? any idea?